# Why do the functions $e^{{-x}^2}$ and $\cos^{2}(x)$ have similar values for $x \approx 0$?

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function

I was playing around on Desmos (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b0oqpa6zp2) with bell functions and ran into a seemingly unusual relation between them and the $\cos$ function. More specifically,

> I am curious about why the function $e^{{-x}^2}$ and the function $\cos^{2}(x)$ have similar values for $x \approx 0$. Why is this?

Comment: I don't think there is too much to this aside from the fact that they have the same first $3$ derivatives at $x=0$, so the Maclaurin expansions around $0$ will be very close to each other.

Comment: I had assumed it had something to do with the Maclaurin expansion being similiar. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If a function can be derived $n$ times at a point $p$, there exists a very nice degree $n$ polynomial that can neatly approximate this function at that point. You can look up "Taylor expansion" (or "Maclaurin expansion") for more information.

It just so happens that for your two functions, these polynomials match for the first terms of the polynomial, making them be closely related around the point 0.

Edit:
In response to a comment, here's some WolframAlpha:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+expansion+of+e%5E%28-x%5E2%29

> $$e^{-x^2} = 1 - x^2 + \frac{x^4}{2} - \frac{x^6}{6} +...$$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+expansion+of+cos%5E2%28x%29

> $$\cos^2(x) = 1 - x^2 + \frac{x^4}{3} - \frac{2x^6}{45} +...$$

As you can see, the first 4 terms match:

- constant/degree 0 => 1,
- degree 1 => 0,
- degree 2 => -1,
- degree 3 => 0,

but degrees 4 don't match, with the former having $\frac{1}{2}$, and the latter having $\frac{1}{3}$ as respective coefficients in their expansion.

Comment: Why not show the first few terms of the two expansions so the OP can see where they first differ?

Comment: @EthanBolker done

Comment: Well... Eventhough I appreciate the answer I feel it doesn't quite answer the question; it just leaves other questions open. E.g. Why are the derivitaves of these functions the same?

Comment: @ProductivePerson The derivatives are the same because Euler's formula $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta))$ connects the exponential and trigonometric functions when you allow complex variables. For the real variable explanation you just manipulate the power series you learn in calculus.